# SQLAlchemy engine from Airflow database hook

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow

What's the best way to get a SQLAlchemy engine from an Airflow connection ID?

Currently I am creating a hook, retrieving its URI, then using it to create a SQLAlchemy engine.

```py
postgres_hook = PostgresHook(self.postgres_conn_id)
engine = create_engine(postgres_hook.get_uri())
```

This works but both commands make a connection to the database.

When I have "extra" parameters on the connection a third connection is needed to retrieve those (see [Retrieve full connection URI from Airflow Postgres hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61528418/retrieve-full-connection-uri-from-airflow-postgres-hook))

Is there a shorter and more direct method?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To be clear, indeed your commands will make two database connections, but it's to two separate databases (unless you're trying to connect to your Postgres Airflow database). The first line of initializing the hook should not make any connections. Only the second line first grabs the connection details from the Airflow database (which I don't think you can avoid), then uses that to connect to the Postgres database (which I think is the point).

You can make slightly simpler though with:

```
postgres_hook = PostgresHook(self.postgres_conn_id)
engine = postgres_hook.get_sqlalchemy_engine()
```

That seems pretty clean, but if you want to get even more direct without going through `PostgresHook`, you could fetch it directly by querying Airflow's database. However, that means you're going to end up duplicating the code to build a URI from the connection object. The underlying [implementation of get_connection()](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/secrets/metastore.py#L34-L40) is a good example if you want to proceed with this.

```
from airflow.settings import Session

conn = session.query(Connection).filter(Connection.conn_id == self.postgres_conn_id).one()
... # build uri from connection
create_engine(uri)
```

Additionally, if you want to be able to access the `extras` without a separate database fetch beyond what `get_uri()` or `get_sqlalchemy_engine()` does, is you can override [BaseHook.get_connection()](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/96697180d79bfc90f6964a8e99f9dd441789177c/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py#L82-L88) to save the connection object to an instance variable for reuse. This would require creating your own hook on top of `PostgresHook`, so I understand that may not be ideal.

```
class CustomPostgresHook(PostgresHook):

    @classmethod
    def get_connection(cls, conn_id):  # type: (str) -> Connection
        conn = super().get_connection(conn_id)
        self.conn_obj = conn  # can't use self.conn because PostgresHook will overriden in https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/hooks/postgres_hook.py#L93 by a different type of connection
        return conn

postgres_hook = CustomPostgresHook(self.postgres_conn_id)
uri = postgres_hook.get_uri()
# do something with postgres_hook.conn_obj.extras_dejson
```

Some built in Airflow hooks have this behavior already (grpc, samba, tableau), but it's definitely not standardized.

Comment: `get_sqlalchemy_engine` is excellent, thank you. Is there a neater way to include any "extra" params from the connection? This is the subject of my linked question

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for your complete answer.
My question is whether we can have a connection pool on Postgres database using this Airflow Hook. Because, if we don't have connection pool, lots of concurrent tasks may incur a heavy load on pg database.

Comment: @mm49307 you can solve the pooling problem with airflow task pools.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer (get_sqlalchemy_engine()) is now partially incorrect due to SQLAlchemy no longer accepting the "postgres:/" prefix. It must be "postgresql:/"

According to this Issue - it effectively used to always work "by coincidence" not by design.

This is the function I use

```html
def get_postgres_sqlalchemy_engine(self, hook, engine_kwargs=None):
        """
        Get an sqlalchemy_engine object.

        :param engine_kwargs: Kwargs used in :func:`~sqlalchemy.create_engine`.
        :return: the created engine.
        """
        if engine_kwargs is None:
            engine_kwargs = {}
        conn_uri = hook.get_uri().replace("postgres:/", "postgresql:/")
        conn_uri = re.sub(r"\?.*$", "", conn_uri)
        return create_engine(conn_uri, **engine_kwargs)
```

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/34876

https://lists.apache.org/thread/8rhmz3qh30hvkondct4sfmgk4vd07mn5

> Historically before `DbApiHook` was introduced some "DB-API 2" Hooks
> (I put in quotes because not all properly implements this API),
> implements this method in each hook separately, and some of them are
> not implemented at all.
>
> Everything changed since DbApiHook introduced and now 23 Community
> Hooks based on it. DbApiHook implements it by interesting way.
>
> def get_uri(self) -> str: """ Extract the URI from the connection.
>
> :return: the extracted uri. """ conn =
> self.get_connection(getattr(self, self.conn_name_attr)) conn.schema =
> self.__schema or conn.schema return conn.get_uri()
>
> And it use by default in
>
> def get_sqlalchemy_engine(self, engine_kwargs=None): """ Get an
> sqlalchemy_engine object.
>
> :param engine_kwargs: Kwargs used in
> :func:`~sqlalchemy.create_engine`. :return: the created engine. """ if
> engine_kwargs is None: engine_kwargs = {} return
> create_engine(self.get_uri(), **engine_kwargs)
>
> IMO there are two bad assumptions:
>
> 1. "You could transform the Airflow Connection URI to the SQLAlchemy URI". Many of the providers also have additional extra parameters
>    which are not supported by SQLalchemy. In additional every changes in
>    Airflow Connection URI format might breaks result even if it worked
>    before: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/34456
> 2. "All DB implements SQLALchemy Dialect ( https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/) and we have packages for
>    it"
>
> I've split Hooks by different groups
>
> Group 1 (7 Hooks): In the first glance works fine but better if
> someone also could have a look
>
> - SnowflakeHook from `snowflake` provider
> - BigQueryHook from `google` provider
> - SpannerHook from `google` provider
> - RedshiftSQLHook from `amazon` provider
> - OdbcHook from `odbc` provider
> - DrillHook from `apache.drill` provider
> - DruidDbApiHook from `apache.druid` provider
>
> Group 2 (10 Hooks): Do not overwrite DbApiHook.get_uri implementation
>
> - MySqlHook from `mysql` provider. In additional this hook provide support for two different drivers:
>
> - mysqlclient: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/
> - mysql-connector-python: https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/
>
> - OracleHook from `oracle` provider
> - JdbcHook from `jdbc` provider
> - TrinoHook from `trino` provider
> - HiveServer2Hook from `apache.hive` provider
> - ImpalaHook from `apache.impala` provider
> - DatabricksSqlHook from `databricks` provider
> - ExasolHook from `exasol` provider
> - PrestoHook from `presto` provider
> - VerticaHook fromvertica` provider
>
> Group 3 (3 Hooks): Uses Connection.get_uri for construct SQLalchemy
> URI
>
> - PostgresHook from `postgres` provider
> - MsSqlHook from `microsoft.mssql` provider
> - SqliteHook from `sqlite` provider
>
> Group 4 (2 Hooks): Implementation which would not work with
> `get_sqlalchemy_engine` method
>
> - PinotDbApiHook from `apache.pinot` provider, seems like it generate URI for broker
> - ElasticsearchSQLHook from `elasticsearch` provider, `elasticsearch` ( https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) do not provide
>   DB-API2/SQLAlchemy interface, `elasticsearch-dbapi` (
>   https://github.com/preset-io/elasticsearch-dbapi/) was removed in
>   apache-airflow-providers-elasticsearch>=5.0
>
> Group 5 (1 Hook): Hooks from suspended providers
>
> - QuboleCheckHook
>
> I'm not sure what we can do in the current situation. My proposal:
>
> 1. Add UserWarning in DbApiHook.get_uri and maybe in DbApiHook.get_sqlalchemy_engine which inform that this methods might
>    not work correctly without re-implementation
> 2. Implements `get_uri` without Connection.get_uri for Group 3
> 3. Raise NotImplemented error in `get_sqlalchemy_engine` for Group 4
>
> My hope for collective wisdom/mind and help in solving this puzzle by
> proposing other ideas.
>
> ---- Best Wishes
> *Andrey Anshin*